# AWS redirect http to https this request has been blocked; the content must be served over https

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, ssl, redirect, https

I am developing an application using AWS, SSL (Load Balancer), PHP.

my domain is example.com

when I access https://example.com

Why when I debug url, which I see is http://example.com althought my browser also display HTTP (usingSSL)

When I call a API from my application I got an error said that "redirect http to https this request has been blocked; the content must be served over https. "

I am using load balancer redirect to target group in AWS.

I tried set

`if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') { return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; }`

but my problem still isn't resolve.

Help me check it

[image]

Other information:

I call a HTTP API, it isn't redirect to HTTPS.
What is problem?
I checked as below site:
https://aws.amazon.com/vi/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/

Comment: What are your listener rules for http to https redirection?

Comment: I have load balancer (listener 80 and 433)  which Default: forwarding to Target groups (protocol 80, type: intance)

Comment: Yes, but listener 80 should be setup to redirect to 443. So ALB does redirection, not your app. Did you set it up like this?

Comment: I tried to set up as https://gyazo.com/c5788229347e8ed02ec86f71ca6be985 but problem can not be resolved